# In iOS 5.1 after dismissing MFMailComposeViewController my UIWebView page java script not working and not loading data from disc cache

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am opening web url in `UIWebView` which contains some buttons with java script actions. There is a button in this page email after hitting this button I get email address and email body in

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{if( [requestString rangeOfString:@"email.com"].location!=NSNotFound){if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){if (!mailer)
                 mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

               mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
                NSString *subject = [dataManager.dictTransalations objectForKey:@"71"];
                [mailer setSubject:subject];

                NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:distributorEmailAddress.length > 0 ? distributorEmailAddress:@"", nil];

                [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
                [mailer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
                isFromMailVC=YES;

                //[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:NULL];
                [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
                }}return NO;} 

- (void)mailComposeController(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
    NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
    break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
    NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
    break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
    NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
    break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
    NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
    break;
    default:
    NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
    break;
}
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@" Mail Composer Error = %@",error);
}
```

After dismissing `mailComposeController` `UIWebView` java script does not work on other buttons and also in another tab  hit another web url that contains some product list also shows blank with head image.

When I see the data in cache in documents directory its there in 100000.db for List table.

I don't why it does not load after opening and dismissing mailcompose. after quitting app from background it works.

Is there any way to debug `UIWebView` page in iOS 5.1 ?

Comment: Can you show your viewwillappear code?

Comment: @Sim actually nothing in ViewWillapper also it does not call when dismissViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same thing in iOS7 yesterday and found a solution a few minutes ago. Maybe it will help you.

Check your `viewWillDisappear` method. Mine looked like this:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    self.webView = nil;
    // whatever else you do
}
```

The error was in the assignments: when `MFMailComposeViewController` appeared and `viewDidDisappear` was called, `webView` lost its delegate and because of that clicks weren't captured.

If you're programming for iOS6 or newer, you should just leave it like that:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    // whatever else you do
}
```

But if you're programming for iOS5 or older and *have to* assign `nil` for some reason, then add this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
    self.webView = nil;
    // whatever else you do
}
```

Note: this method is **deprecated** for iOS6 and newer, as it is never called since iOS6.